# Session state of ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am new to Android App development, working on an android app which populate a list of numbers, in a listview dynamically, depending on the choice of the user, but, the moment user closes the App, the items in the listview are lost. How can I maintain the state of the listview?

Examples with code would be highly appreciated.

When I open Activity A, it allows users to add friends, and this friend list is shown in the form of items of listview in the same Activity, however, when I move to Activity B, and then come back to Activity A, this friend list disappears. I need to make sure that this friend list should not be lost while moving between activities. Please help.

Comment: Have a look at this question from SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example this will guide you through

Comment: @MDMalik: Thanks for your response, but, what you had suggested works well to maintain the session of an application whereas I need the to maintain the items of Listview. When I open Activity A, it allows users to add friends, and this friend list is shown in the form of items of listview in the same Activity, however, when I move to Activity B, and then come back to Activity A, this friend list disappears. I need to make sure that this friend list should not be lost while moving between activities. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that for your purpose there are 3 main methods, i'll explain them from the easier to the most difficult (in my opinion).

**Text File**

A way to do this is to create two methods in a class:
one has to create the text file in the storage if it isn't created before and read that, the other has to `append` a `String` to a `StringBuilder` and write it on the previous text file.

For this method you need the `uses-permission` of reading and writing to storage.

This link can help you: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

**JSON** (also XML)

With JSON file you can create a list of objects with your data that you can serialize when you update the list and deserialize when you want to read it. For this purpose you have to study JavaScript syntax or, at least, JSON one.

**SQLite Database**

Android SDK incorporate a class named `SQLiteOpenHelper` that you can extend to create a database inside your app.

This link can help you: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

---

There are also references saving methods but i think that aren't right for your purpose, they work betters to save something like preferences or single data like last login informations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It was of great help, but, didn't resolve my issue. I need to maintain the session state of items of Listview. The one you gave works well with textview, but, didn't help me with items of Listview.

Comment: @User11012 On JSON you can store arrays and lists, on txt file you can save array or list objects separated by \n with properties separates by semicolons, with database you can store properties of an object, so why it didn't work?

Comment: I am actually not sure when the listview is resumed, how would I update the UI of listview with the data of the DB. Could you please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I went through your comment. I would personally suggest using `SQLiteOpenHelper`

You might need to understand the use of SQLite, hence the [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Simple Flow. On your `Activity 1` where person `Add` Friends save it to `DB`
Then refresh the `List` from the `DB`. So when you move to `Activity 2` and come back again to `Activity 1` your `List` will refresh from `DB`. Hence no loss of data as you want.

**EDIT**

As user wanted to know how to use the `ListView` with `DB`.

Following are my suggestion

- [Sai Geetha](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2011/02/listview-of-data-from-sqlitedatabase.html)
- [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-7sW6UJHw0)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have saved the data in DB, however, I am not sure how my list will refresh from DB. It would be extremely nice if you could guide me on this.

Comment: Please have a look at the EDIT